# iphone MPMoviePlayerViewController CGContext Errors

Tags: iphone, xcode, cgcontext

I am writing an app for the iPhone that will play some movies utilizing `MPMoviePlayerViewController`.  So far I have gotten it to play movies, however it is throwing some errors in the debugger that all start with `CGContext`.  I have wracked my brain in trying to fix it.  Here are the details of my code:

.h file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>
@interface MovieViewController : UIViewController {
    MPMoviePlayerViewController *playerController;
}

-(IBAction) playMovie:(id)sender;
```

.m file:

```
@interface MovieViewController ()
@end
@implementation

-(IBAction)playMovie:(id)sender {
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]
                                     pathForResource:@"moviename" ofType:@"mp4"]];
playerController =  [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc]
                     initWithContentURL:url];
[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:playerController];
playerController.moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeFile;
[playerController.moviePlayer play];
playerController = nil; 
}
```

When I run the program the movie will play, however when the code executes the line: `playerController =  [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];` the following errors occur:

```
<Error>: CGContextSaveGState: invalid context 0x0
<Error>: CGContextClipToRect: invalid context 0x0
<Error>: CGContextTranslateCTM: invalid context 0x0
<Error>: CGContextDrawShading: invalid context 0x0
<Error>: CGContextRestoreGState: invalid context 0x0
```

I do know that `invalid context 0x0` means that those specific variables do not have a value, but I have no idea how to remedy this.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Very nice description of the problem.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I was having the same issue. Merely saying this:

```
MPMoviePlayerViewController* mpvc = 
    [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL: m];
```

was causing these `invalid context` error messages. The view controller's view (the fullscreen player) did appear when presented, and played the movie no problem; the only issue was these error messages, which I didn't want showing up in the console.

Taking a hint from Norman's solution, I simply wrapped the call in an artificial drawing context, like this:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(1,1));
MPMoviePlayerViewController* mpvc = 
    [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL: m];
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

It's silly, but it works.

Comment: this works. though can you please explain why there's problem at the first place and why this solution works. In my ipad 6.1 simulator, the problem won't occur; it only occurs in my iphone 6.1 simulator.

Comment: thanks! really saved me I was starting to go insane with this issue.

Comment: I also had to disable my all-purpose breakpoint for "all exceptions", as this issue would cause the debugger to breakpoint-stop 30+ times.  With that breakpoint disabled, and the graphicsContext fix above, I get no problems from the simulator/debugger.

Comment: @ObjectiveTC I agree. The problem is that "all exceptions" can stop on exceptions even if they are caught by the framework - they are not really problems, and would not crash your app in the wild, but they are acting as breakpoints when running in Xcode. - However, that has nothing to do with the above problem; it really *is* a problem. It's not an exception; it's a bunch of error messages appearing in the log.

Comment: @Till Pointless. It's fixed in iOS 7, and they're not likely to go back and fix iOS 6.

Comment: Glad to hear that it got fixed. I haven't done any iOS 7 development (but plenty of 3,4,5 and 6).

Answer (score 8):

I think the error messages are a bug in MPMoviePlayerViewController

They don't seem to be fatal, although I've made them go away by adding a 
call to UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size); in both readyPlayer()
and viewDidLoad().

I also added a UIGraphicsEndImageContext() to dealloc() to clean up the generated contexts.

Comment: That is an extremely clever solution. See my modification below.